# Add the previous row value in commutative manner

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am stuck in this query. Table T1 is like:

```
Name ID
A    1 
A   -1
B    2
C    3
C    4
E   -1
```

I need output like:

```
Name ID   Output
A    1      1
A   -1      0
B    2      2 
C    3      5
C    4      9
E   -1      8
```

What I have tried:

```
SELECT t.NAME,
        cs.[Count(ID)]

FROM   T1 t
        CROSS apply (SELECT Sum([ID]) [Count(ID)]

                    FROM   T1  t1
                    WHERE  t1.ID <= t.ID ) cs
```

I am not getting the correct output because it is ordering by Id not name or may be any other issue.

Comment: Thanks Zhorov for suggesting the edits.

Comment: Try searching before posting - running totals have been discussed many, many times for all versions of sql server

Answer (score 1):

You can use *window* function :

```
sum(id) over (order by name, case when id < 0 then 1 else 0 end, id)
```

You can also use `apply` :

```
select t1.*, t11.Output
from t1 t1 cross apply
     (select sum(t11.id) as Output
      from t1 t11
      where t11.? <= t.? -- Use ordering column instead.
     ) t11;
```

Comment: I have a doubt here.. I have never used sum () over function. Will it work in SQL server 2008 version? @yogesh Sharma

Comment: SELECT t.NAME,
        cs.[Count(ID)]

FROM   T1 t
        CROSS apply (SELECT Sum([ID]) over (order by name ) [Count(ID)]

                    FROM   T1  t1
                    WHERE  t1.ID <= t.ID ) cs   ---- If i am running the above query then I am getting error as Incorrect syntax near 'order .... Please suggest

Comment: Thanks @yogesh its working now using apply function. I think the SUM () Over is not supported by 2008 version of SQL as it is throwing the error. 'Incorrect syntax near 'order'.
'